# Sum in echo php

Tags: php

I'm a little bit discouraged because of PHP behavior.
Why does PHP interprets my code in this way:

```
echo "We has over " . 2500 + 500 . " employees over the world"; // 500 employees over the world
```

Comment: Operator precedence.... because `+` and `.` have equal precedence, and are both left associative, you're effectively doing `(("We has over " . 2500)  + 500) . " employees over the world"`

Comment: Enclose calculations  with parenthesis. Operator precedence rules!

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Now I understand :)

Comment: Nice findings. Normally we used to put brackets, but haven't going beyond the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the above code into:

```
<?php
$sum=2500 + 500;
echo "We has over " . $sum . " employees over the world";

?>
```

Comment: I'm interesting why does PHP cut the string.

Comment: See my comment against your question for the explanation of why